# Python: How to compare two 2-dimension lists, process its values and store it in a new one?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have the following lists:

```
TAKEOFF LIST:  [['EHAM', 55], ['EGLL', 46], ['LOWW', 44], ['LFPG', 43], ['LTBA', 38], ['EDDF', 37], ['LEMD', 34], ['EKCH', 33], ['EGKK', 31], ['LFPO', 30], ['LEBL', 28], ['LEPA', 28], ['LIRF', 25], ['EBBR', 25], ['ENGM', 23]] 

LANDING LIST:  [['LEMD', 38], ['EDDM', 35], ['LEBL', 34], ['LFPO', 33], ['LFPG', 32], ['EKCH', 29], ['LTBA', 27], ['ENGM', 25], ['LSZH', 25], ['LTFJ', 24], ['LOWW', 23], ['EHAM', 23], ['EGKK', 22], ['EDDL', 22], ['ESSA', 21]]
```

I want to compare both lists, if the first item for every row exist in both lists, then add it  to a new lists with both values and the sum of it.

Example output top 3 by the sum of its values:

```
OUTPUT_LIST: [['EHAM', 78, 55, 23], ['LFPG', 75, 43, 32], ['LOWW', 67, 44, 23]]
```

Constraints: The final structure must be a lists of lists and this is just a simplified part of the original code. Actually the lists are composed from reading a file with thousands of lines (up to 500000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are not really ideal for that kind of data. You should consider storing the data in e.g. dicts in the first place. However given input and output lists as above, we could first convert to dicts (using dict comprehensions) and then back to a double list using a list comprehension:

```
takeoffs = {k: v for k, v in takeoff_list}
landings = {k: v for k, v in landing_list}
output = [[k, v1+landings[k], v1, landings[k]] for k, v1 in takeoffs.items() if k in landings]
```

Note that this code does not check for errors, e.g. for duplicate items in either list.

Comment: Does the job for me Jussi. I do have the same algorithm done with dictionaries, but I need to compare executions times for demonstration. I've done all the checking previously in the code, not to worry.